# Passing Constrained Generic Type to Non-Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, casting

Why can't I pass an instance of this class...

```
class Item<T> where T : Thing { }
```

...into this method:

```
void DoSomething(Item<Thing> item);
```

Since I've constrained `Item<T>` to be an `Item<Thing>`, it should be safe to cast before sending my item through to `DoSomething` - but why doesn't the framework handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a class:

```
public class SomeOtherThing : Thing { }
```

An `Item<SomeOtherThing>` can *not* be cast to an `Item<Thing>`.  They are not the same.

Let's assume for a moment that item looks something like this:

```
public class Item<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

`DoSomething` might then do something like:

```
void DoSomething(Item<Thing> item)
{
    item.Value = new Thing();
}
```

If you pass in an `Item<SomeOtherThing>` to `DoSomething` you have now just assigned a new `Thing` to `Value`, **but value is a property of type `SomeOtherThing`, you cannot set a `Thing` object to it**.  This would have then broken the type system.  The compiler knows that this is an option.  Because of this (and any number of other operations that have the same fundamental problem) a `Item<SomeOtherThing>` can not be cast to an `Item<Thing>`.

So, what can you do?

Well, if you control the definition of `DoSomething`, perhaps it too should be generic.

If `DoSomething` looks like this:

```
void DoSomething<T>(Item<T> item)
    where T : Thing
{    }
```

Then you can call it with an `Item<SomeOtherThing>` since the operations that previously would have caused problems are no longer valid from within `DoSomething`.

Comment: Thank you, I often forget about covariance, etc. That's a good reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine

```
class Derived : Thing {}
```

The `Item<Derived>` is not assignable to `Item<Thing>`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be a little more specific in the method declaration like so;

```
void DoSomething<T>(Item<T> item)
    where T : Thing
{
    // now your method knows that T must be of time Thing and you can use it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that your method is specific to `Item<Thing>`, and `Item<Something>` is not a valid argument. C# does not support generic class covariance. You have several options.

The "easiest" thing to do is to simply make your method generic and add a constraint to Thing. This would be the first advised approach.

```
void DoSomething<T>(Item<T> item) where T : Thing
{
}
```

This will grant you access to all members of `Thing` as applicable, while still having a method that can cater to all subclasses.

Another option with more limitation is to have a non-generic base to `Item<Thing>` that is simply `Item`. (In it, wherever you were previously exposing T, you would expose `object`. Think: `IEnumerable<T>` : `IEnumerable`.)

```
void DoSomething(Item item)
{
}
```

Your method would simply expect `Item` and you could work with it. But if you have a specific requirement to work with `Thing`, it is a bit more delicate, you would need to cast as appropriate, but you also face the possibility that someone passes an instance that *isn't* an `Item<T>` where T is a Thing.

One other option is to leave the signature of the method alone and convert from a class to an interface, which allows you to use covariance. (Co/contravariance is supported in .NET 4.0 for interface and delegate types.)

```
interface Item<out T> 
{
    T Get();
    // void Set(T foo); // invalid  
}
```

Again, the issues here are that 1) you would need to change your type (obviously) but 2) you would be limited to only exposing `T` in output positions. Notice the `Get()` method is supported. A `Set(T)` method is not, because `T` is an input, which makes the interface not covariantly valid. (Imagine passing in an `Item<Something>`, and your method trying to call `Set` with `SomeOtherThing`. Both are `Things`, but clearly the second is not appropriate for the first.) So if you need to support `T` as both outputs *and* inputs, you could not utilize this approach.

Comment: Thanks. My `Item<T>` actually is an `IItem<T>` and an `IItem` so I just ended up expanding and passing an `IItem` instead.